# Find the optimal font size for a defined width/height

Tags: php, gd

Can some one tell me if there is a function in php which does the opposite of imagettfbbox function? ie it should take in the 8 coordinates and font etc and return me the optimal font size. I know we can implement our function for this  but is can I get some ready made function for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP GD Font Width Calculate Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809200/php-gd-font-width-calculate-help)